# WickedPDF Intermittently Generates Corrupt / Damaged File

Tags: pdf, wicked-pdf

I'm generating PDF's from user supplied data. 95% of the time, good PDFs are generated. In debug mode, everything looks OK. How should I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 2):

I posted in the Issues section of the github account: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/607

> After a while, I figured out that it was a case of nested "no-break" div's. (Which are pointless anyway, but something to look for if you're encountering this maddening problem).

Further explanation:

In order to prevent page-breaks in the middle of a section, I assign a class no-break with the following rules:

```
.no-break:before {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.no-break {
  page-break-inside: avoid !important;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

And the following HTML formatting:

```
<div class="no-break">
  .... some user supplied content
  <div class="no-break">
    .... more user supplied content 
  </div>
</div>
```

If the inner div.no-break needs to be moved onto the next page to avoid a break, it will corrupt the PDF.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Hey ,I'm facing the same problem (random corrupt files) weird thing is 1 of 100 times I can generate this corrupt file perfectly. The file is always the same, and your css code didnt work. Any advice ?

Comment: @llermaly This post about nested no-break divs is just one cause for corrupt files being generated. If I were to generalize on why it happens, a file is corrupt because didn't finish generating (something like missing closing tags). So a more general description of the cause would be print specific CSS rules (like page-break: avoid;) that would throw off the generator.

Comment: Hey @Nick , I'm pretty sure my problem is the same, I removed my no-pagebreak rule from last child and file rendered, but I need to avoid pagebreaks in that zone too. This code is not mine and I cant make it work, I had to go to the html file itself and modify the question html length ( I'm using 3 levels of nesting. Question group statement -> question -> selections(A,B,C,etc).

I will attach my code just in case you can help me easily. We had to fight for weeks to get the results the client wanted. http://pastebin.com/p6C0SmWw